# androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn Android development, but the problem is that my app crash every time I tried to run it and I get these errors in logcat:

```
2019-06-30 16:17:18.198 5317-5317/? E/e.myapplicatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2019-06-30 16:17:20.551 5317-5317/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 5317
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:23)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="click me"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here the java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void onButtonClick (View view){

    TextView t1 = findViewById(R.id.text);


    t1.setText("Hello ss");

    EditText  e1 = findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);

    t1.setText(e1.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the ContraintLayout tag have a corresponding closing tab?

Answer (score 21):

This is because both your `ConstraintLayout` and `TextView` is sharing the same id `text` in your layout XML file. As a result, when you try to refer the `TextView` in your Java code via `R.id.text`, it links to your `ConstraintLayout` instead which causes the crash.

Change the id of your `ConstraintLayout` to something else (like `mainlayout`).

Like this (copy and replace your XML code with the below) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="click me"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The ConstraintLayout and the TextView use the same ID. Rename the ID of the ConstraintLayout to something different and use `@+id/text` instead of `@id/text` in your TextView, so the ID is generated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using the id of text_view but the layout practically contains constraintlayout
so just alter the layout to have a text view instead of constraintlayout

Answer (score 1):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />
```

Your ConstraintLayout and Textviw have the same id Check it.

> android:id="@id/text"

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because in Your XML file you are using the same id  "text"

for `layout` and `Textview`.
your XML file should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/text"                      ///////////////// here 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@id/text"                        ///////////////// here 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="click me"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have give the **same id to your TextView or the ConstraintLayout**.

You can simply solve this issue by removing the **android:id="@id/text"** which you have given to the ConstraintLayout or name it something else like **android:id="@id/parentLayout"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="click me"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```